# Prefer32Bit Flag on project file

Tags: web-config, clr, app-config, .net-4.5, corflags

When changing a project from targeting .NET 4 to .NET 4.5 I get the following added to the project file for each build configuration:

```
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

What does this mean? The only [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.managedcompiler.prefer32bit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I could find on MSDN wasn't too clear.

Comment: It was added to support ARM cores.  It solves the ambiguity between "I need an x86 core" and "I don't want to run in 64-bit mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sets the 32BITPREFERRED flag. The app runs as a 32-bit process even on
>   64-bit platforms. Set this flag only on EXE files. If the flag is set
>   on a DLL, the DLL fails to load in 64-bit processes, and a
>   BadImageFormatException exception is thrown. An EXE file with this
>   flag can be loaded into a 64-bit process. New in the .NET Framework
>   4.5.

From the Corflags documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx